# How can I make Windows Media Player ignore global hotkeys in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, hotkeys

I have Windows 7 and a Logitech G15 keyboard.

One of the programs with the Logitech G15 allows you to control media players such as Winamp with the playback keys on the keyboard.

Problem I'm having is that, even though I have told this program to not control Windows Media Player, every time I use it to pause Winamp, it then hits plays (or unpauses) Windows Media Player. Even more annoying given that Windows Media Player isn't even running as an active GUI program and instead as a background process, so I hear the sound of whatever the last video it was I playing.

If I end-task wmplayer.exe it spins right back up but at least now it has no knowledge of a video to play, but this is annoying.

How can I either

a) Have Windows Media Player in Windows 7 completely unload when I close it, or
b) Have Windows Media Player in Windows 7 ignore any sort of global hotkeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this one out - since I have a Logitech G15 keyboard, Windows 7 installed Windows SideShow and attached to it.

So the SideShow feature was keeping Windows Media Player alive for me. By going to Control Panel -> Hardware -> Windows SideShow, you can disable or enable what happens with SideShow.

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest solution but you could use [AutoHotkey](http://www.AutoHotkey.com) to catch the [media keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm), and then pass the commands on to the program of your choice.

A link to get your started http://www.techjunkeez.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=887

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to use your keyboard keys to control Winamp, you could remap your keys to Winamp's global shortcuts.
That would not trigger WMP, and only allow Winamp to catch them.
Use a program such as http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html instead of Autohotkey to ease the process

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall WMP by going to control panel > Uninstall a program on the left hand side there will be "Turn Windows features on or off", then when it has loaded expand Media Features and untick Windows Media Player.

You won't be able to open Windows Media Player though until you do the same as above but tick the box instead.